# syntax of basic authentication in web config

Tags: iis

i want to add a password protect a directory to the, but i only found the following code without password

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <allow users="test" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

how do i add the password for the user "test"?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably found your answer by now, but what you need to do is create a local user on your Windows server with the username test and then assign the relevant password to that user. IIS will map entered credentials to the local Windows and will verify the credentials against that Windows user's credentials.
Hope that helps.